# Would it be an acceptable practice to call methods in Exception constructor?

Tags: php

I have my custom Exception class defined like this:

```
class EPPException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($text, $code, $message = null) 
    {
        EPPHelper::logError($text, $code, $this->getTraceAsString, $message);
        parent::__construct($text, $code, null);
    }
}
```

And the exception is thrown

```
throw new EPPException($text, $code, $message);
```

My question is - is it acceptable from the design point of view to use constructor not only to initialize the object but carry on some additional tasks like calling a static method in this case?

**UPDATE**

Another option would be to create a static method that handles the logging and throws the exception

```
class EPPException extends Exception
{
    public function __construct($text, $code, $message = null) 
    {       
        parent::__construct($text, $code, null);
    }
}

public static function raiseException($text, $code, $message = mull)
{
    EPPHelper::logError($text, $code, $this->getTraceAsString, $message);
    throw new EPPException($text, $code, $message);
}

EPPHElper::raiseExeption($text, $code);
```

The problem with this approach is that it will mess up the stack trace

Comment: Looks good. Why not ?

Comment: Just make sure there is no way for your exception handler to throw an exception and you end up stuck in a loop

Comment: Why create static methods, when you can stop the charade and use functions with global variables? (because that's basically what you are currently doing)

Comment: Log and throw is useful but still an anti-pattern, as you will now be logging the exception in two places. I strongly recommend reading and understanding https://today.java.net/article/2006/04/04/exception-handling-antipatterns

Comment: Thanks for the link, worth reading through in a spare time. A quick glance and I saw exactly my approach in a list of antipatterns...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

[Business logic in the constructor makes your code untestable.](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/)

Besides which, it is not the job of an exception or its emitter to perform logging, it is the job of the exception *handler* to take the appropriate action, which may including logging the error somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, please take a look at my updated question

Comment: @VladimirHraban You're still doing the logging in the wrong place. The `catch` block should take the appropriate action, such as logging. Also the static logger is a bad plan from a testability and reusability point of view. The general rule (for PHP) is that is you think you need a static member on anything, you don't.

Comment: There are various places in different places where the exception can be thrown. I will have to copy over logging method over and over again

Answer (score 1):

Please do not do that, neither of them.

An exception just to describe the problem occured in code.

It is suggest to catch the exception in some place, then handle the exception, for example, do logging, make some warning.